# How do I stop a router.post in express from killing a previous call to the same route?

Tags: node.js, angular, express

My environment is an Angular front end with an Express/Nodejs backend.

An example of my issue is a user clicks a button on a web page that kicks off a long running SQL process. This is connected to the DB using an Angular service which makes an HTTP request against a route. This route hits a post on the Express side which executes the SQL statements. If another user on the site hits the same route it will kill user 1s query. How do I stop this?

Example Below:

**Service in Angular**

```js
getBBB(id): Observable<[BBBResult]> {
  const url = 'http://localhost:4200/'+'job_bbb';
  const data = ({
    id: id,
  });
  return this._http.post(url, data)
  .pipe(
    map((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      return <[BBBResult]> res;
    })
  );
}
```

**Routes/Index.js file in Angular**

```js
router.post('/job_bbb', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.body.id;
  var sql = " CALL PROCEDURE DB.PROC(" + id + ");"
  return database.read(sql)
    .then((x) => {
      console.log(x)
      res.send(x);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Differents calls to express should not interrupt themselves since your route has to be stateless.

Have a look to your database driver provider, and check examples of use.